# Postgres on Mac - tablefunc extension control file path is wrong

Tags: macos, postgresql

On Mac Server OSX 10.9.5 running Postgres 9.3.4
I'm trying to run a crosstab query, but was getting

```
ERROR: function crosstab(unknown, unknown) does not exist
```

so, I tried to install `tablefunc`, but now getting:

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file 
"/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/postgresql/extension/tablefunc.control": No such file or directory
```

So, looks like some search path somewhere is screwed up.
Any ideas how to fix?

EDIT: This obviously has to do with having two Postgres instances on the machine, at

```
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin/psql
```

and

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/psql
```

And currently only the /Library version has tablefunc.control underneath it.  So the first question is - should I try to switch which instance of Postgres the machine uses?  Or should I try to install tablefunc into the /Server.app instance?

Answer (score 0):

This problem disappeared magically after I upgraded to Yosemite